# Exporting photos ... how to efficiently handle such requests?

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm working on a web app that inventories your home items.  I'm 90% there except now I need to figure out a way to export photos should the user so chooses.  I've managed to export the items into a CSV file, but what good is that if they can't have their photos?  I'm currently using MongoDB for the backend, but regardless of how I store them, I need a way where a user clicks a button "Export Photos" and it gets compress into one file for the user to download.

My only concern is what if they've stored hundreds of photos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid blowing out your php process, I'd recommend you dump the files out of MongoDB one by one in a temporary directory on the filesystem, and then use `exec` combined with `tar` or `zip` to turn it into a compressed archive that you send to the user.

Of course this could end up in a pretty bad DDoS of your site, so you'd better write that in a careful way, i.e. if the user has more than 100 images, using a queue with Gearman or some RabbitMQ server might be a good thing, and then you could tell them they will get an email once their archive download link is ready or something? It shouldn't be a daily thing to export all your pictures I assume, so may be acceptable.

Comment: I would definitely look into Gearman and you're right, it could get messy and the last thing I want to avoid is a user clicking like there's no tomorrow. What I may end up doing is making it a manual process. The chances of someone needing to download their entire archive are slim but if the user needs them, I wouldn't mind doing it manually and providing a link to download.

Answer (score 0):

You can record their last attempt at exporting the archive and only allow it once every hour or so (they may do something wrong the first time so it's always a good idea to not have a too long expiration period).

Comment: True but the more I think about it, the more issues I may encounter. I would like to make the whole site self sufficient but at what cost? I've looked at some of my competitors site and many of them do not offer the ability to export photos. That's something I want to address but maybe I should just release now and worry about that later. ;-)